# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 Array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I need some help with this one.  I have trying to get this array to work properly but do not know what I am doing wrong. I am a noob to java and really need some help

```
   private static int respondentID; 
    private static int count; 

    static void enterQuestions() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    private String surveyName; 
    private boolean surveyStart = true;  
    private boolean surveyStop = true; 
    private String question [] = new String[10];
    private int responses[][]= new int[10][10];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // first overloaded constructor                                          
    public Phase2() {                    

        this( "Customer Survey" );
        respondentID = 0;
        count = 0;        
    } // end 

    // second overloaded constructor
    public Phase2( String title ) {

        surveyName = title;
        respondentID = 0;
        count = 0;
    } // end constructor Survey

    // method to be called when a user starts filling out a survey ( surveyStart will have been set to "true" )
    public int startSurveyCount( int ct ) { // parameter for testing only

        if( surveyStart ) {              

            if( respondentID > 0 ) { 


                if( count >= respondentID ) {

                    count++;
                } else {


                    setCount( getRespondentID() );
                }
            } else { 
                //test
                setCount( ct );  
                count = getCount(); 
                count++;
                setCount( count - 1 ); 
            } 
        }  

        return count;
    } // end method

    // method to be called when a survey is successfully 
    public int generateRespondentID() { 
        if( surveyStop ) { 
            // 
            count = getCount();                       
            setRespondentID( count ); 


        } else {                

            if( count < 2 ) { 
                count = 0;     
                respondentID = 0;
            } else {
                count--; 
                setCount( count );
            } 
        }

        return respondentID;
    } // end method generateRespondentID

    public void setRespondentID( int count ) {
        // count is the number of completed surveys. 
        respondentID = count; 
        respondentID++;       // and then incremented by 1.
    } //end method

    public int getRespondentID() {
        return respondentID;
    } // end method 

    public void setSurveyTitle( String title ) {

        surveyName = title;
    } // end method 

    public String getSurveyTitle() {
        return surveyName;
    } // end method 

    public void setCount( int ct ) {

        count = ct;
    } // end method 

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    } // end method

    public void setSurveyStart( boolean surveySt ) {

        surveyStart = surveySt;
    } // end method 

    public boolean getSurveyStart() {
        return surveyStart;
    } // end method 

    public void setSurveySubmit( boolean surveySub ) {

        surveyStop = surveySub;
    } // end method 

    public boolean getSurveySubmit() {
        return surveyStop;
    } // end method 

    public void logResponse(int respondentID, int questionNumber, int responseEntered)
    {
        responses[respondentID] [questionNumber-1] = responseEntered;
        }
   public void displaySurveyResults (int no)
   {
       for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
       System.out.print("Question"+(no)+" : " + question[no-1]+"Reply");
       if (responses[respondentID][no] == 0)
       {
           System.out.print("NO");
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.print("Yes");
   }
   }
  public void enterQuestion()
  {
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter Question "+(i+1)+" : ");
          question[i] = input.nextLine();
      }
  }
  public void displayQuestionStats(int no)
    {
        int answer;
        System.out.print("Question"+(no)+" : "+question[no-1]+" (0-No/1-Yes) : ");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        logResponse(respondentID, no, answer);
    }


}
```

This is my tester

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {




    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Below are the results of running the no–argument");

        // demonstrates the no–arg constructor
        Phase2 noArgSurvey = new Phase2();
        System.out.printf( "The no–argument survey values are:\ntitle:  %s\n"
            + "initial value of respondentID:  %d\ncount:  %d\n", 
            noArgSurvey.getSurveyTitle(), noArgSurvey.getRespondentID(),
            noArgSurvey.getCount() );

        // demonstrates the constructor with a title argument ( for user input of survey title )
        System.out.println( "\nPlease enter a name for the survey" );
        String inputTitle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(); // inserts a blank line
        Phase2 titleArgConst = new Phase2( inputTitle );
        System.out.printf( "Survey Name is: %s\n"
            + "initial values of:\nrespondentID:  %d\ncount:  %d\n\n",
            titleArgConst.getSurveyTitle(), titleArgConst.getRespondentID(),
            titleArgConst.getCount() );

       //respondent id test
        System.out.println( "This will test the generateRespondentID method.\n\n"
            + "Enter the number of surveys that have been taken");
        int testInt = input.nextInt();

        // values for respondentID and count after 1 survey has been successfully submitted
        System.out.println( "\nAssuming " + testInt + " surveys submitted");
        Phase2 oneDone = new Phase2();
        oneDone.startSurveyCount( testInt );
        oneDone.generateRespondentID();
        System.out.printf( "The Respondent ID is: %d\ncount: %d\n\n", 
            oneDone.getRespondentID(), oneDone.getCount() );       

        noArgSurvey.enterQuestion();

         for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
         {
            noArgSurvey.displayQuestionStats(i);
         }

         //Display The Inputs Entered by User
         System.out.println("Result for Survey with Title \""+titleArgConst.getSurveyTitle()+"\" :");
      for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
         {
            noArgSurvey.displaySurveyResults(i);
         }

    } // end main method
} // end class SurveyTest
```

Comment: Arrays are 0-index based. You take care of that in `displayQuestionStats` but not in `logResponse`.

Comment: When you ask a question about an exception, you should indicate the line that throws it. This is information an IDE will tell you in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Change loop condition to

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java follows Zero indexing. So in your case `question` and `responses` array is of size `10` which means it will iterate from `0 to 9` use `for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)` instead for iterating. or use `arrayName.length` `length` is a variable provided by `JVM` which gives you the `size` of array at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

AS Vishrant mentioned **Java follows Zero indexing. So in your case question and responses array is of size 10 which means it will iterate from 0 to 9* *

in your tester class, you are trying to access 10th index in loop in 2 places

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)           (1)
     {
        noArgSurvey.displayQuestionStats(i);
     }

for(int i=1; i<11; i++)                 (2)
     {
        noArgSurvey.displaySurveyResults(i);
     }
```

You should to write

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)           (1)
     {
        noArgSurvey.displayQuestionStats(i);
     }

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)               (2)
     {
        noArgSurvey.displaySurveyResults(i);
     }
```

**EDIT Addition**

```
public void displaySurveyResults (int no)
{
   for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
   System.out.print("Question"+(no)+" : " + question[no]+"Reply");   <<<--------- change [no-1] to [no]  
   if (responses[respondentID][no] == 0)
   {
       System.out.print("NO");
```

}

Comment: its then throwing an error at line 168 on main and line 55 on tester

Comment: How can we know which is line number 168??? You Should to show some of your stack trace

Comment: System.out.print("Question"+(no)+" : "+question[no-1]+" (0-No/1-Yes) : "); is line 168

Comment: noArgSurvey.displayQuestionStats(i); line 55 on tester

Comment: remove [no-1], change to [no]